# why get text returns false?

Tags: android, sms

I wrote this to send my username and password, but it returns `false`. Why?

It sent this message to my phone : `User:falsePass:false`

I have tried `char`,`charSequense`,`string`,... but it always returns `false`

```
package com.example.project6;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class Login extends Activity {
    private ImageView imageview;
    private EditText username;
    private EditText password;
    private Button save;
    private String user;
    private String pass;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    init();

}

private void init() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    username=((EditText)findViewById(R.id.username));
    password=((EditText)findViewById(R.id.password));
    save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            user = getText(R.id.username).toString();
            pass = getText(R.id.password).toString();
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage("+989132249093", null, "User:"+user+"Pass:"+pass, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(Login.this,user, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(Login.this,pass, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(Login.this,"sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

please help me 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
user = username.getText().toString();
pass = password.getText().toString();
```

`getText(int resid)` `Return a localized, styled CharSequence from the application's package's default string table.`
If you have a string declared in `strings.xml` file then it returns that string else returns false.

Answer (score 1):

This would give the value in user and pass if both edit texts are not empty on clicking your button.

```
username=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
password =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
user = username.getText().toString();
pass = password.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this

```
user = username.getText().toString();
pass = password.getText().toString();
```